# Highstock Data points connected auomatically

Tags: highcharts

I created Highstock chart with 3 series,
some of the series have missing data in some time interval.
what the Highstock does is "complete" or "connect" the points to each other but I want it to plot no data in those intervals.

how can I do that?
I tried to set the xAxis intervals but it did not work.
here is some basic example from thewebsite.

[Example from highchars.com](http://goo.gl/ep6Dd)

in this example it does what I want - you can see that there is points which are not connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the 'connectNulls' property:

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.connectNulls

Comment: still doesnt work..,
my data looks like this:
var data1 = [  
[1350511200000, 0],
[1350514800000, 8.4],
[1350518400000, 8.16],
[1350522000000, 8.24],
[1350525600000, 8.4],
[1350529200000, 7.45]];

maby its because how the data is build?

Comment: If you want breaks in the line, you need to use null instead of 0.
You'll probably also need to disable data grouping, if that is being used.